# Converting a NVARCHAR into a UK date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, ssms

I'm looking to convert a users input that will be a NVARCHAR to a UK date

The user's input will always be a maximum of 6 digits.

For example:

151119 (DDMMYY) --> 15NOV19

120119 (DDMMYY) --> 12JAN19

Comment: Not hard, but tedious. There is nothing built into T-SQL that'll give you month names, so you need `SUBSTRING` and a dollop of `CASE ... WHEN '01' THEN 'JAN' WHEN '02' THEN 'FEB' ... END`. In general, of course, you will be much better off using unambiguous formats like `yyyy-MM-dd`, storing dates as `DATE` columns and leaving formatting up to the client.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - both `DATENAME` and `FORMAT` can supply month names

Comment: @MartinSmith: I thought of `FORMAT` right after I said it but I've never used `DATENAME`. (And given its culture-specific output, now that I know of it I never will. But hey, it's something.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have been trying to use FORMAT but that won't work with an NVARCHAR

Comment: Yes, that's why you really want to store dates in `DATE` columns. While you can convert the string to a `DATE` ((through appropriate application of `STUFF` and `CONVERT`) and then `FORMAT` it, that's even more clumsy and roundabout than just doing a substring and `CASE` dance. There's also the matter of two-digit years being ambiguous. Does `SELECT UPPER(FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF('151119', 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-'), 5), 'ddMMMyy', 'en-GB'))` look appealing to you? It looks horrific to me.

Comment: *Don't* allow such input to begin with. What year is 19 anyway? All UI platforms have date pickers, all languages support date types. Even if you say `cutoff year` that changes going forward. If you google for `15 november 1919` you'll find that many sites store such dates and can tell you eg that the Red Army captured Omsk in 14 November 1919

Comment: BTW the `date` type in SQL Server uses 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid [`DATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) or [`DATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) / [`DATETIME2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) value first. You can get this value using this `SELECT` query with `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, 
  SUBSTRING('151119', 3, 2) + '-'
  + SUBSTRING('151119', 1, 2) + '-'
  + SUBSTRING('151119', 5, 2)
, 10);
```

Now you have two possibilities to get the date in the expected format (`DDMMMYY`).

**1 - solution using [`DATENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql):**

```
-- set the date value (from custom date value).
DECLARE @dDateValue AS DATE = CONVERT(DATE, 
  SUBSTRING('150419', 3, 2) + '-'
  + SUBSTRING('150419', 1, 2) + '-'
  + SUBSTRING('150419', 5, 2)
, 10);

-- format the date value to the expected format.
SELECT DATENAME(DD, @dDateValue) + 
  UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @dDateValue), 3)) + 
  RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @dDateValue), 2);
```

**2 - solution using [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):**

```
-- set the date value (from custom date value).
DECLARE @dDateValue AS DATE = CONVERT(DATE, 
  SUBSTRING('150419', 3, 2) + '-'
  + SUBSTRING('150419', 1, 2) + '-'
  + SUBSTRING('150419', 5, 2)
, 10);

-- format the date value to the expected format.
SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dDateValue, 6), ' ', ''));
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=12dcb84f526a7ff906a8183d7d536653)

---

**Note:** I recommend to store the date values on columns with `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type. You can format the date value on your application or using format functions on SQL-Server directly.

Comment: As `DATENAME` is language dependent, you can get surprises with dates like `150419` under `SET LANGUAGE French`. Of course, getting a language-specific date may be exactly what you want, depending on the use case. (There may be languages where the three-letter name for the month is not the first three letters of the month name, so this wouldn't work in the first place, although I don't know if there are.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter the string into something that looks even little like a normal date format, then you can use convert:

```
declare @textDate nvarchar(6) = '120119';

select @textDate
    , stuff(stuff(@textDate, 3,0,'/'), 6,0,'/')
    , convert(date, stuff(stuff(@textDate, 3,0,'/'), 6,0,'/'), 3);
```

Gives:120119,12/01/19,2019-01-12
As that last one is a valid date datatype, you can now use `Format()`.

Though obviously 2 digit years are a bad idea in the first place.

Forgot to say, the 3 is for UK 2 digit format(dd/mm/yy), and you can see the other choices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to work with date values on columns AS DATE or DATETIME type. This is a simple implementation for your need :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/95387/13)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (mydate nvarchar(6))
insert into test (mydate)values('151119')
insert into test (mydate)values('120119')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, dates), 'dd/MM/yyyy ')   from (select left(mydate,2)
+ 
CASE  SUBSTRING(mydate, 3, 2)
       WHEN '01' THEN 'JAN'
       WHEN '02' THEN 'FEB'
       WHEN '03' THEN 'MAR'
       WHEN  '04' THEN 'APR'
       WHEN '05' THEN 'MAY'
       WHEN '06' THEN 'JUN'
       WHEN '07' THEN 'JUL'
       WHEN '08' THEN 'AUG'
       WHEN '09' THEN 'SEP'
       WHEN '10' THEN 'OCT'
       WHEN '11' THEN 'NOV'
       WHEN '12' THEN 'DEC'
       ELSE 'error'
END
+ right(mydate,2) AS 'dates'
from test ) AS T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/95387/13/0)**:

```
|             |
|-------------|
| 15/11/2019  |
| 12/01/2019  |
```

Comment: A [simple CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) would be applicable since only one value is being checked and `like` is not needed: `case Substring( MyDate, 3, 2 ) when '01' then 'JAN' when '02' then 'FEB' ... else 'Thanks for playing!' end`.

Comment: I'd leave out the `ELSE` altogether -- the resulting expression will then become `NULL`, which is highly visible and hopefully easy to diagnose (as opposed to the string potentially becoming too long, or worse, being silently accepted with the "error" right in there).